# Convert a 3d point into camera uv coordinates

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader, panda3d

I have a 3d point defined as follows :
`vec3(1, 1, 0.0)`
I want to transform it to uv coordinates while knowing

```
vec3 camera_pos;//The camera position
vec3 camera_rot;//The camera rotaion in degrees
float fov;//The camera field of view
```

But I can't figure out the math can someone help please ?